# <div> with float: left not going left

Tags: html, css

This should be pretty basic CSS, but no matter what I try, the damn `div` just won't go where it should!

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="c_container">
<div class="c_title">Registe-se</div>
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="c_data_container">
        <div class="c_columns">Nome:</div>
        <div class="c_data">
            <input type="text" name="name" value=""  required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
        <div class="c_columns">Email:</div>
        <div class="c_data">
            <input type="email" name="email" value=""  required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
        <div class="c_columns">Telefone:</div>
        <div class="c_data">
            <input type="text" name="phone" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
        <div class="c_columns">Morada:</div>
        <div class="c_data">
            <textarea name="address1" ></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
        <div class="c_columns">Morada para envio se diferente da fiscal:</div>
        <div class="c_data">
            <textarea name="address2" ></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
        <div class="c_columns">N. Contribuinte:</div>
        <div class="c_data">
            <input type="number" name="fiscal" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
        <div class="c_columns">Palavra passe:</div>
        <div class="c_data">
            <input type="password" name="password" value=""  required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="passreq">* A palavra passe deve conter pelo menos um número e/ou letra maiúscula.</div>
<input type="submit" name="addcdata" value="Salvar"/>
</form>
</div>
```

And this is the css:

```
div.c_container {float:left;width:100%;text-align:left;}
div.c_container .c_title {float:left;width:100%;text-align:center;line-height:35px;font-weight:bold;margin:20px 0;border-bottom:1px solid cor01;}
div.c_container .c_data_container {float:left;width:31%;margin:10px 1%;}
div.c_container textarea, div.c_container input[type=number], div.c_container input[type=text], div.c_container input[type=email], div.c_container input[type=password] {border:0;width:98%;height:20px;background-color:cor09;padding:3px 5px;border-radius:5px;}
div.c_container .passreq {float:left;width:96%;margin:5px 2%;text-align:left;font-size:12px;line-height:16px;}
div.c_container input[type=submit] {float:right;padding:5px;border-radius:0;margin:20px 1% 0 0;}
```

And for some reason it looks like this:

[image]

The password is on the right side instead of the left. Why? I've tried using `display:inline-block` and that didn't work either.

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/h7qmyumr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the height on c_data_container.
Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydmbke5z/)
specifically the height is missing; this should be enough:

```
height: 45px;
```

Without the height this is what is happening:[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you are floating all `div`, the div in left (Morada para envio se diferente da fiscal:) of 'Palavra passe:' have height more than 'N. Contribuinte' which causes last div to float to 'Morada para'.

For solving this issue you should `clear` it. clearing means restricting the `div` to not allow any other floated elements near it.

For that change the code as:

```
<div class="c_data_container clear">
        <div class="c_columns">N. Contribuinte:</div>
</div>
```

and in CSS:

```
.clear {
   clear: both;
}
```

like in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h7qmyumr/1/

But the problem is now you can't have any other `div` floated to it: for solving that issue you could add `clear` class to an empty `div`, so that it will act as a boundary between group of `div`s. Like in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h7qmyumr/4/

Comment: This is the proper way to handle the issue.

Comment: @Simon I agree - this is the better way, I'm not sure what I was thinking with the max-height (I need a coffee), I'll remove my answer as this should be marked as the correct one. +1'd

Comment: @Simon I agree also. It is why I have deleted my answer :)

Comment: I don't see the problem you mentioned with the clearing @Asim, you can properly align other floating elements with the cleared one, it might be better to only `clear: left` though.

Comment: Btw, you could also use an `nth-child` selector to automatically clear every element needed (i.e. every item that moves to a new line): `c_data_container:nth-child(3n+1) { clear: left; }`. Note that this is not properly supported by [IE8 and below](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child).

Comment: You are right @Simon. But we normally use clear-fix to clear both floats.(Like in BootStrap). `clear:left` is enough for the problem, but I was adding that information since it is good for general cases rather than specific issues. (Think if we use `float:right`)

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the float set by previous element. Add `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` before the container. Check below update.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
div.c_container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
div.c_container .c_title {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid cor01;
}
div.c_container .c_data_container {
  float: left;
  width: 31%;
  margin: 10px 1%;
}
div.c_container textarea,
div.c_container input[type=number],
div.c_container input[type=text],
div.c_container input[type=email],
div.c_container input[type=password] {
  border: 0;
  width: 98%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: cor09;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
div.c_container .passreq {
  float: left;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 5px 2%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
div.c_container input[type=submit] {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 20px 1% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="c_container">
  <div class="c_title">Registe-se</div>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="c_data_container">
      <div class="c_columns">Nome:</div>
      <div class="c_data">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
      <div class="c_columns">Email:</div>
      <div class="c_data">
        <input type="email" name="email" value="" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
      <div class="c_columns">Telefone:</div>
      <div class="c_data">
        <input type="text" name="phone" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
      <div class="c_columns">Morada:</div>
      <div class="c_data">
        <textarea name="address1"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
      <div class="c_columns">Morada para envio se diferente da fiscal:</div>
      <div class="c_data">
        <textarea name="address2"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
      <div class="c_columns">N. Contribuinte:</div>
      <div class="c_data">
        <input type="number" name="fiscal" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="c_data_container">
      <div class="c_columns">Palavra passe:</div>
      <div class="c_data">
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="passreq">* A palavra passe deve conter pelo menos um número e/ou letra maiúscula.</div>
    <input type="submit" name="addcdata" value="Salvar" />
  </form>
</div>
```